# IOS App Id type in provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning

I'm very new to IOS so pardon my "rookieness".  My question is: Is there a way to tell whether an App_Id is either wildcard or explicit in the apple provisioning profile's page?  I see the ids are there but I can't tell what type of Id it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to tell is via the 'App IDs' section in the Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles tool.  When you look at the string that appears in the "ID" column, if it ends with an asterisk ('*') then it is a wildcard AppId:

[image: Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles AppID ScreenClip]

Within the Provisioning Profiles area you can also locate this information but it is an extra click away.  Navigate to the 'Provisioning Profiles' section and click on the profile you want to find out more about.  Within the details that appear, the section 'App ID' contains both the AppID Name and the AppID itself. As with the "App IDs" section from above, if the ID ends in asterisk ('*') then it is a wildcard AppID:
[image: Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles Provisioning Profiles ScreenClip]